# How to get a list of WMI classes in certain path (using C#)?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

With `C#`, How to get a list of `WMI` classes in certain path, such as `root\WMI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms257362%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**Edit:**

On function AddClassesToList

```
private void AddClassesToList(object o)
{
    this.statusValue.Text = "Searching...";
    try
    {
        // Perform WMI object query on 
        // selected namespace.
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            new ManagementScope(
            namespaceValue.Text),
            new WqlObjectQuery(
            "select * from meta_class"),
            null);
        foreach (ManagementClass wmiClass in
            searcher.Get())
        {
            this.classList.Items.Add(
                wmiClass["__CLASS"].ToString());
            count++;
        }
        this.statusValue.Text =
            count + " classes found.";
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        this.statusValue.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

This part :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
new ManagementObjectSearcher(
new ManagementScope(
"root/default"/*Replace this with your namespace*/),
new WqlObjectQuery(
"select * from meta_class"),
null);
```

Comment: I've seen that, still don't know how to search within specific path such as `@"root\WMI"`

Comment: explained on the answer